# Plot which parameter where in R?

Tags: r, plot, par

So... I'm looking at an example in a book that goes something like this:

```
library(daewr)
mod1 <- aov(height ~ time, data=bread)
summary(mod1)
...
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(mod1, which=5)
plot(mod1, which=1)
plot(mod1, which=2)
plot(residuals(mod1) ~ loaf, main="Residuals vs Exp. Units", font.main=1, data=bread)
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
```

That all works... but the text is a little vague about the purpose of the parameter 'which='.  I dug around in the help (in Rstudio) on plot() and par(), looked around online... found some references to a different 'which()'... but nothing really referring me to the purpose/syntax for the parameter 'which=' inside plot().

A bit later (next page, figures) I found a mention of using `names(mod1)` to view the list of quantities calculated by `aov`... which I presume is what which= is refering to, i.e. which item in the list to plot where in the 2x2 matrix of plots.  Yay.  Now where the heck is that buried in the docs?!?

Comment: Look at `class(mod1)` and then search for the appropriate method in either `methods(thatclass)` or showMethods(class="thatclass"). Then read the help page for the function. Or perhaps just do this: `help(plot, pack=daewr)`

Comment: `class(mod1)` returns "aov" "lm".  `methods(lm)` and `methods(aov)` didn't pan out.  `showMethods()` for either didn't work, just complained that they weren't S4 generic functions. `methods(lm)` yielded something, but not quite.  `methods(plot)` yielded another list... including `plot.lm`.  `help(plot.lm)` yielded the answer I was looking for.  Kind of a round-about way of finding what seems like it should have been a lot easier... but it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: So, if you look at output from `methods(plot)` and see nothing for 'plot.aov' and do see a 'plot.lm' (perhaps with an asterisk after it if it is not "exported"), then you know that the `mod1`-object will be given to a function actually named `plot.lm`. So type `?plot.lm` at the console and your question will be answered.

Comment: Thought that was pretty much what I said... ;)

Comment: It sounded to me that you were looking at the help page for `plot.default` and could not find the listing of the `which` parameter on the help page. At the top of the `plot.lm` help page is a listing of the six plots returned by `plot.lm` and then `which` is described as a vector containing one or more of the numbers corresponding to those descriptions. Further details are in the Details section. It's unclear what more is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`which` selects which plot to be displayed:

1. A plot of residuals against fitted values
2. A normal Q-Q plot
3. A Scale-Location plot of sqrt(| residuals |) against fitted values
4. A plot of Cook's distances versus row labels
5. A plot of residuals against leverages
6. A plot of Cook's distances against leverage/(1-leverage)

By default, the first three and 5 are provided.

Check `?plot.lm` in r for more details.